# QOS Layer 2 Link

Tags: qos

I have two NET APP Controllers in two different Data Centers. The Data Centers are connected with a 1 Gig Layer 2 connection. Both NET App controllers are IPed within the same broadcast domain. The communication traffic over this 1 Gig connection is mostly sync traffic between the two NET App's. During busy periods the sync traffic can take up 95+% of the link. Is it possible to rate limit or shape this communication traffic to 80% of the 1 gig link?

Comment: Could you please add a diagram explaining your topology?

Comment: GREATLY depends on the switching infrastructure between the two filers. I happen to know both topics and would be glad to answer if you can fill in the blanks on what's used.

Comment: what kind of sync protocol do you run?

Comment: snapmirror/snapvault traffic is the sync traffic between the two Netapp's. One Netapp is plugged into a Cisco 6500 and the other is plugged into a Cisco Nexus 5k. Both devices are interconnected over the 1 gig link (layer 2) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can throttle the Netapp's snapmirror/snapvault traffic from Netapp's System Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution is to attach a policer to the access ports:

```
!
policy-map ingress-limit
 class class-default
  police 800M 1000000 exceed-action drop
 !
!
interface gigabitEthernet0/1
 description port connected to NetApp
 service-policy input ingress-limit
!
```

Or, else, you should deploy something more sophisticated and QoS mark your packet at the ingress on access ports and shape them with WRR at the egress on uplink ones.
In that way you would throttle NetApp's up to 80% only when congestion occurs.

```
!
mls qos
!
class-map match-any bulk-data
 match input-interface gigabitEthernet0/1
!
!
policy-map classifier
 class bulk-data
  set dscp AF11
 class class-default
  set dscp AF31
!
interface range gigabitEthernet 0/1 - 22
 service-policy input classifier
 srr-queue bandwidth shape  0  0  0  0
!
interface range gigabitEthernet 0/23 - 24
 description uplink ports
 srr-queue bandwidth shape  0  0  0  0
 srr-queue bandwidth share  1 80 20 1
!
```